# Rails 3 Custom Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I'm attempting to created a custom validation that verifies a schedule's start_date and end_date do not overlap with another schedule

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
#has many scheduleTimes (fk in scheduleTime)
has_many :scheduletimes, :inverse_of => :schedule 

validate :dateOverlaps?

scope :active, lambda {
 where('? between start_date and end_date', Date.today)
}
def dateOverlaps?
  results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select (start_date::DATE, end_date::DATE) OVERLAPS ('#{self.start_date}'::DATE, '#{self.end_date}'::DATE) from schedules;")
  errors.add_to_base("Date ranges cannot overlap with another schedule") if                   results.first["overlaps"] == 't'
end
```

however, this causes

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_to_base'
```

I have tried creating a custom validator and using the private validate method to no avail. Could someone shine some light on this for me?

Comment: Just a quick comment, your method doesn't respect Ruby's convention. "dateOverlaps" should be named "date_overlaps".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
errors.add_to_base("Date ranges cannot overlap with another schedule")
```

with this:

```
errors.add(:base, "Date ranges cannot overlap with another schedule")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
errors.add_to_base
```

try using:

```
errors.add
```